# Why are not checkboxes displayed in block mode ? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Well this is not about CSS and this is about Javascript.
As far as I know block mode display elements in a new line whereas inline mode display elements without starting a new line :[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp).

Please look at the below javascript
It simply displays a set of checkboxes once a main checkbox is clicked. If not they are hidden.

```
function prepareEventHandlers(){
//This is the main checkbox
var mainCheck=document.getElementById("mainCheck");

//This is the corresponding div
var displayResult=document.getElementById("showHide");


    mainCheck.onchange=function(){

    //check whether the state of the checkbox is checked or not
        if(mainCheck.checked){
        //if it is checked the div is displayed
            displayResult.style.display="block";

        }
        else{
        //if it is not clicked div is not displayed
            displayResult.style.display="none";

        }



    };
//div is set to not to display in the initial page load
     displayResult.style.display="none";

}


//prepareEventHandlers() will be executed once the page is loaded.
window.onload=function(){
prepareEventHandlers();

}
```

The code works fine. But I want you to focus on these few lines

```
if(mainCheck.checked){

displayResult.style.display="block";

            }
```

Even though display mode is block all my checkboxes appear inline when the main checkbox is clicked. Why is that?
Any kind of explanation will be highly appreciated

Comment: you can't change certain styles of some elements (eg checkboxes and drop down lists).  If you google styled checkboxes you will see there are a lot of js plugins that help achieve a "styled" checkbox whereas in fact all you are doing is styling the label

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: because checkbox is an inline element. And you are changing `style.display` property of the `div`, not individual checkboxes You said it in comment:

```
//div is set to not to display in the initial page load
displayResult.style.display = "none";
```

I suppose you have your checkboxes inside this `div#showHide` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/um5R5/

Comment: yes you are correct. It is my mistake. It is my div that I have applied style on. BTW thanks for the clarification :)